Origin of the round square triangle puzzle
I need to refer, in a research paper, to the solid mentioned in this old thread:
Is there a name for a 3D shape that looks like a circle when viewed from one axis, a square from another, and a triangle from the third?
Like the original poster seven years ago, I'd love to know the name of the solid - a question that doesnt seem to have been fully answered. But I'd also appreciate information on the origin of the concept - which seems to have begun as a  puzzle.
Some internet sources credit it to George Hart - isn't it way older? I mean, a couple centuries or more?
And, lazybones that I am, does anybody have a picture of it I could use? With all due attribution and credit of course.

FYI, I believe a question like this one may be better suited for the History of Science and Mathematics SE site. Nonetheless, before possibly posting any questions there, please first check for duplicates, read their Help Center such as about what types of questions to avoid asking and what topics you may ask there, etc.

I don't know of a name for it. Looks something like the head of a cold chisel:

You might be able to find a better picture. You could surely draw one with openscad.

Btw, this name has common origin with "scissors" (french "ciseau (à bois)")
